# Recycler view doesn't display any data?? Log shows error "E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout"

Tags: firebase, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to display data from my firestore database with a recycler view. The app doesnot crash but displays no data. Log cat shows
**E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout**
Here is my code

- **Fragment** where i need to display data

  ```
   public class ProductFragment extends Fragment {
   private static final String TAG = "ProductFragment";
   private FirebaseFirestore firestoreDB;
   private RecyclerView productRecyclerView;

   public ProductFragment() {
  // Required empty public constructor
  }


   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                       Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // Inflate the layout for this fragment

  View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_product, container, false);
  firestoreDB = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
  productRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.events_lst);


  LinearLayoutManager recyclerLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
  productRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(recyclerLayoutManager);

  DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(productRecyclerView.getContext(),
                                                              recyclerLayoutManager.getOrientation());
  productRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);

  getDocumentsFromCollection();

  return view;

  }
  @Override
   public void onAttach(Context context) {
  super.onAttach(context);
  }


     public void getDocumentsFromCollection() {
  firestoreDB.collection("products").get()
          .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
              @Override
              public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                  if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                      for(DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()){
                          Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " =>" + document.getData());
                      }
                      List<Event> eventList = new ArrayList<>();

                      productRecyclerViewAdapter recyclerViewAdapter = new productRecyclerViewAdapter(eventList, getActivity(), firestoreDB);
                      productRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
                      productRecyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);

                  } else {
                      Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                  }
              }
          });

  firestoreDB.collection("products")
          .addSnapshotListener(getActivity(), new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
              @Override
              public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {


              }
          });
  }
  }
  ```
- **Adapter**

  public class productRecyclerViewAdapter extends
          RecyclerView.Adapter {

  ```
  private List<Event> eventsList;
  private Context context;
  private FirebaseFirestore firestoreDB;

  public productRecyclerViewAdapter(List<Event> list, Context ctx, FirebaseFirestore firestore) {
      eventsList = list;
      context = ctx;
      firestoreDB = firestore;
  }

  @Override
  public int getItemCount() {
      return eventsList.size();
  }

  @Override
  public productRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder
  onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

      View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
              .inflate(R.layout.list_layout, parent, false);

      productRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder =
              new productRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
      return viewHolder;
  }

  @Override
  public void onBindViewHolder(productRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
      final int itemPos = position;
      final Event event = eventsList.get(position);
      holder.item_name.setText(event.getName());
      holder.price.setText((int) event.getValue());


  }

  public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

      public TextView item_name;
      public TextView price;


      public ViewHolder(View view) {
          super(view);

          item_name = view.findViewById(R.id.List_maintext);
          price = view.findViewById(R.id.List_subtext);

      }
  }
  }
  ```
- **Fragment Layout**

  ```
  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
      android:id="@+id/events_lst"
      android:scrollbars="vertical"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
      app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view_event"/>
  ```

  Please help with this

Comment: You set the adapter inside an if-statement. Are you sure this statement actually triggers?

Comment: @Androidas This is the same as shown in the firebase documentation. I don't know if there is a mistake.